# iOS tel hyperlink javascript tracking in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, google-analytics, tel

I have some js code to record outbound link click events in Google Analytics, which effectively adds a delay to the click event before allowing the normal click behaviour to go through.

This applies to both `http` as well as `tel:` links. I trigger a specific "phone number has been clicked" event in GA so we know the user intended to make a call (whether or not they go through with it is a different issue entirely).

The number of events being tracked into GA seems strangely low and with anecdotal testing, many deliberately triggered events don't seem to show up in GA (I.e. I sit on my phone and press the link a few times).

I wonder why this could be.

#### Does iOS do something weird to immediately halt or bypass my javascript when a `tel:` link is clicked? If not, what could explain the lack of event tracking going on here?

For context, I'm talking about tracking the click event **before** the call prompt comes up:

[image: iOS call prompt]

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue (working with jquery) and found out that it occurs when i tried to recognize the tap with jquery click handler.
i found a solution with adding

```
jquery.on("click touchstart", function(e){...});
```

now it works fine again on desktop and mobile/touch browsers (tested on newer ios and android devices) and the call-prompt is displayed immediately.

Comment: That's really interesting. We're using Google's GTM built-in "Click - just links" event, which obfuscates the actual event it's binding to. (Can't find any docs, which is infuriating). I wonder if it binds to "click" which never fires as the "click" event only fires after "ontouchend" which doesn't happen if iOS interrupts to show the call dialog. Hmmmmm.

Comment: i guess this behavior is pretty new on mobile devices, since we usually test such events on desktop and mobile for new properties. we did recognize it first time a few weeks ago. maybe something has changed in ios/android which gtm needs to catch up? although pretty strange that both os would release it nearly at the same time ...